# I can't get in to my Google+ account; I don't know what email I used

Tags: google-plus, google-account, password-recovery

I made a Google Plus account for my business a few years ago and now I need to edit it.

I tried all my Gmail accounts to retrieve it, yet none of them work. How can I find the correct email used to create the account so I can edit or remove it?

Comment: Is this a regular Google+ profile or is it a Google+ Page? (If it's for your business it _should_ be the latter.)

Answer (score 2):

In [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/#contacts), when you add a Google email address to a contract, it will show you the connected Google+ profile, if there is one.

So just add all of your Google email addresses to one or more contacts and watch for the connected Google+ profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to send a message to that profile and see what email address receives the notification.

One way is to create a G+ post (with another account, obviously) and share it only with the profile you're trying to reach.

There's also, depending on settings, a "send message" icon displayed under the profile picture.

Or you might simply add the profile to a Circle; there would be a notification sent about that. (This also depends on privacy settings, but it's on by default.)